# How to clear cache when use byte buddy

Tags: java, javaagents, byte-buddy

```
package com.example;

public class Car {

    private String name;
    private String model;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

The other class Dependent is

```
package com.example;

public class Dependent {

    public  Car callMethod2(){

        Car car = new Car();
        car.setModel("2009");
        car.setName("Tata");
        return car;
    }
}
```

The other class Main is

```
package com.example;

public class Main {

    public static String callMethod1(){
        return "Hello from callMethod1";
    }

    public static Car callingCall2(){
        Dependent call = new Dependent();
        Car args= call.callMethod2();

        return args;
    }
}
```

The other class MainTest is

```
package com.example;

import static net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation.to;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassReloadingStrategy;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MainTest {

@Test
public void Test1_withByteBuddy()
        throws Exception {
    ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    new ByteBuddy()
            .redefine(Dependent.class)
            .method(named("callMethod2"))
            .intercept(to(Cardetails.class))
            .make()
            .load(MainTest.class.getClassLoader(),
                    ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
    Car car = Main.callingCall2();
    System.out.println(car.getModel());
    System.out.println(car.getName());
    assertEquals("2011",car.getModel());
    assertEquals("Maruti",car.getName());
}

public static class Cardetails {
    public static Car car() {
        Car carTest = new Car();
        carTest.setModel("2011");
        carTest.setName("Maruti");
        return carTest;
    }
}

@Test
public void Test2_withOutByteBuddy()
        throws Exception {
    Car car = Main.callingCall2();
    System.out.println(car.getModel());
    System.out.println(car.getName());
    assertEquals("2009",car.getModel());
    assertEquals("Tata",car.getName());
}
}
```

Here when I run my MainTest the second method `Test2_withOutByteBuddy()` is failing . Why Because it is taking values which is generated by byte buddy from method `Test1_withByteBuddy()`. So, here how can I clear the values generated by byte buddy once its execution completes and how I will get my expected values from method `Test2_withOutByteBuddy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke:

```
ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent().reset(Dependent.class)
```

Doing so, Byte Buddy resets the class to its original class file representation.

Ideally, you should do this within a try-finally block or a `@After` method to ensure the reset even if the test fails.

Comment: Thanks for your response , But it is working when I run (Run As  Junit Test). But if I run (Coverage As Junit Test) am getting below error .Is there a way to use same for code coverage.                                                  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)